# The method "collection" isn't defined for the type FirebaseStorage

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm getting an error trying to store data in firestore. Another issue is using my emulator in android studio ( pixel 5 ) or even all my 4 connected devices. I can run but they all show nothing. Flutter doctor finds no issues. Please help I'm tryna make an application I can't see but rather use my imagination of how it'd looks and this is not the correct way.

````
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:swift_mobile/constants.dart';
import 'user_model.dart' as model;

class AuthController extends GetxController{

  static AuthController instance = Get.find();

  late Rx<File?> _pickedImage;

  File? get profilePicture => _pickedImage.value;

  void pickAnImage() async {
  final pickedImage = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
  if(pickedImage!=null) {
    Get.snackbar('Profile Picture', 'You\'re good to go!');
   }
   _pickedImage = Rx<File?>(File(pickedImage!.path));
  }

  Future<String> _uploadToStorage(File image) async {
    Reference ref = firebaseStorage
        .ref().child('profilePictures')
        .child(firebaseAuth
        .currentUser!.uid
    );
    UploadTask uploadTusk = ref.putFile(image);
    TaskSnapshot snap = await uploadTusk;
    String downloadUrl = await snap.ref.getDownloadURL();
    return downloadUrl;
  }

  void registerUser(String username, String email, String password, File? image) async {
    try{
      if(username.isNotEmpty &&
          email.isNotEmpty &&
          password.isNotEmpty &&
          image!=null) {
       UserCredential cred =  await firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
           email: email, password: password);
        String downloadUrl = await _uploadToStorage(image);
        model.User user = model.User(name: username, email: email, uid: cred.user!.uid, profilePic: downloadUrl);

        await firestore.collection('user').doc(cred.user!.uid).set(user.toJson());
      } else {
        Get.snackbar(
            'Error creating account',
            'Please enter all fields',
        );
      }
    } catch(e) {
      Get.snackbar(
          'Error creating account',
          e.toString());
    }
  }
} ```
````

Comment: [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) aka [Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore) is a distinct service. You don't appear to be importing the relevant Firestore package, see: https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore

Answer (score 0):

Replace `firebase.collection` with :

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection
```

And import Firestore. It's a different thing from storage.